# Azure automation powershell, not work int input parameter

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I use azure automation,
and have code like this

```
workflow Report
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string] $Name,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Int] $MyCount
    )

    inlinescript
    {
       Write-Verbose "Name $Name"
       Write-Verbose "Count $MyCount"
    }
}
```

in Test pane (on https://portal.azure.com) I set next value for this parameters: "Test" and 2 
In console I see next result:

```
Name Test
Count
```

$Name working good 
but $MyCount not showed

According to documentation I'm doing everything right
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx

How I can use int input parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according this post https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574197.aspx
in **inlinescript** I don't have access to main variables 
for get main variable I need use **$Using**

```
Write-Verbose "Count $Using:MyCount"
```

Comment: but then why do you have access to $Name since both $Name and $MyCount are parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I noticed that my runbook type had to be "PoweShell Workflow Runbook" under Other.

When I had selected just PowerShell none of my parameters would appear in my Test pane