# PowerShell Reserved Variable Names

Tags: variables

Is $input a reserved variable name?

```
PS C:\Users\caec> $inp = "ehlo"
PS C:\Users\caec> $inp
ehlo
PS C:\Users\caec> $input = "wtf"
PS C:\Users\caec> $input
PS C:\Users\caec>
```

It seems I can't set $input to anything. Any idea why?;)

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable and you can't use it for normal purposes: [Why `$input` can only be accessed once](https://superuser.com/q/1767894/241386), [powershell, not work int input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35227543/995714), [Why does PowerShell code behave different when called from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54091971/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Powershell, what is $input for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241124/in-powershell-what-is-input-for)